# recursively check all folders and export the list of folders that has no created backup file in it during last 24 hour

Tags: powershell-4.0

There is a folder containing database backup files. I need to recursively check all folders and export the list of last backup files in each folder.

I have a code here that contains my idea. just I have to add this part:
-check for each selected file(selected file is the last created backup file) if the file creation time is older than 24 hours, export in csv file.

Thanks in advance

```
[Cmdletbinding()]
param(
  [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$path=
  "\F:\backups",
  [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
$OutPutFilepath=
"f:\backup-daily.csv" 
)

function Get-LastestWroteFile{
   [Cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]$Folder
    )
    begin{
        $Latest = Get-ChildItem $Folder.FullName -File | select FullName, 
CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Attributes,  @{N='SizeInMb';E= 
{$_.Length/1mb}},Name | Sort-Object CreationTime | select -Last 1
    }
    process{

    }
    end{
        #new custom object with 3 props.
       if($Latest){
            return New-Object PSobject -Property @{"FullName"=$latest.Name; 
      LastWriteTime = 
$latest.LastWriteTime;"Folder"=$folder.FullName;"SizeInMB" = 
[math]::Round($Latest.SizeInMB,3)} #FileInfo=$Latest; }
        }
   }
}

$OutPut=@()
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $path -Recurse | foreach{
    $OutPut+= Get-LastestWroteFile $_
}

$OutPut | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -delimiter '|' | Out-File - 
FilePath $OutPutFilepath
```

Answer (score 0):

an advanced function would not be required, try below

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File | Where-Object -FilterScript {
    ([Datetime]::Now - $_.CreationTime ).Hours -gt 24
} | Select-Object -Property Name,LastWriteTime,FullName,@{N='SizeInMb';E= 
{$_.Length/1mb}},
```